# Bernoulli's inequality and sequences

Tags: inequality, bernoulli-numbers

How can I use Bernoulli's inequality to prove $c^{1/n}\to1$ for $c>0$ ?

I have to use $c^{1/n}=1+xn$.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

We have that for $c>1$

$$1\le c^{\frac1n}=(1+(c-1))^{\frac1n}\le 1+\frac{c-1}n$$

Comment: thank you...!!!

Comment: @christina09 Recall that we also need to prove the case $0<c<1$.